# Existe documentação oficial para o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, documentação

Existe alguma documentação oficial do JavaScript assim como tem o PHP.net ou o jQuery.com? Quando procuramos no Google não aparece nada parecido a JavaScript.com...

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no Meta: [Reabertura de Tópico - Manual Oficial de JavaScript](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2152/201)

Comment: Já te dei a dica mais de uma vez e fiz edições nos seus posts esperando que servissem de exemplo... é importante fazer um título descritivo da situação. Tem gente que vai votar negativo só por causa disso, tem gente que vai editar a pergunta para tentar melhorá-la. Ah, sim, esta pergunta foi parar na fila de análise de Perguntas de Baixa Qualidade devido ao comprimento, tenho certeza que não quer seu nome associado com isso... Se lê em inglês, este tutorial do Jon Skeet é definitivo: [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @MarcosvInicius: Foi justamente por ver potencial de agregação na sua pergunta que levei ela para o META. No futuro, **depois de seguir** aquilo que você já viu fazerem ao editar seus tópicos, se você tem plena consciência de que o que escreveu basta, mesmo que este seja negativado, ignore. O pessoal aqui vive com coceira no dedo pra dar um *downvote*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O que chamamos de JavaScript é uma implementação do **[ECMASCRIPT](http://www.ecmascript.org/)** (ECMA-262). Existem várias versões que vão sendo desenvolvidas. Atualmente está implementada a versão 5 na maioria dos browsers.

No site da **[ECMASCRIPT](http://www.ecmascript.org/)** pode encontrar-se documentação sobre JavaScript. Porém é num formato académico bem pesado, e nada garante que browsers diferentes apliquem o código como é descrito e especificado alí.

Assim a fonte mais respeitada e usada no dia-a-dia é a **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)** (Mozilla Developer Network) que tem uma documentação bem completa e que tem informação sobre a compatibilidade e implementação de dado método nativo nos browsers mais comuns. A **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)** é uma wiki e é activamente atualizada pela comunidade que a usa.

Outra função importante que a **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)** desempenha é disponibilizar scripts, chamados Polyfil, que corrigem ou permitem funcionalidades que não existem em browsers mais antigos. A **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)** é também uma referência importante para HTML e CSS.

**P.s.** - Vale a pena referir [a nossa wiki aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)!
É uma página que tem informação geral sobre o JavaScript e links importantes para aprender e saber mais sobre a linguagem.

Comment: Relacionado [Discouraging w3schools as a resource](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87678/185667) & [Can we retract the use of `rel=nofollow` for links that reference the MDN documentation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253420/1287812)

Comment: @brasofilo boa, isso merecia quase uma pergunta resposta para mais pessoas saberem a qualidade dos conteudos da w3schools.

Comment: O W3Schools quebrou um bom galho durante muito tempo. Mas tudo que um dia teve seu ápice, decai com o tempo. E os administradores do site sequer se mexeram nesse anos todos enquanto o MDN se fortalecia. Sinto cheiro de um "bem feito" ^_^